# Dialogflow CX: Intents, Entities and Route Group changes not captured by a version

Tags: dialogflow-cx

When I create changes on the intents like creating a new one. I want to saved this in a specific version/environment. However, these new intents are only saved on the draft environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version is bound to a flow. So after you change an intent, it will be deployed to the flow (which contains that intent) in the draft environment automatically. It will not be deployed to other environments.

So you need to create a new version of the flow (that changed) from the draft environment and then deploy that version to a specific environment.

You can check the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/version).

Comment: thanks for answering! How do i link the new intent to a flow?  btw,when i donwload/export the agent. Intents are not seen inside a flow. It has a seaparte intent folder. can you share some insights how intents are linked to a flow? is it linked by the annoated entities of the training phrases?

Comment: yeah, i can linked the intent to the flow by using it as routes. thanks!